# How to use locally js files in vue components?

Tags: vue.js

I have an animation js file, that I'm trying to use on a specific vue component. I tried to use import, required and mounted(), but none of that worked so far

```
 <template>
 <div class="home">
<audio controls="controls" src="../assets/raindrops-in-the-ocean.mp3"></audio>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
</template>
   <script>
    require('../assets/raindrops.js');

     export default {
     name: 'raindrops-in-the-ocean',
     components: {
     },
created() {
let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')
recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', '../assets/raindrops.js')
document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript)
},
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does your build process look like?

Comment: Do you mean npm run build?

Comment: Good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56639128/2162226

Answer (score 1):

By using below import statement you can use locally javascript file:

```js
<script>
    import '../assets/raindrops.js';
    
    export default {
        name: 'raindrops-in-the-ocean',
        components: {},
        created() {
            let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')
            recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', '../assets/raindrops.js')
            document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript)
        },
    } 
</script>
```

Note: It is recommended to use relative path instead of absolute path for importing any file